# How do I create a conditional statement to sort through this data and apply a template if the data is found?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create an xsl:if statement that will apply a template if certain criteria is met.

Here is my XML file. I want to find parks that I can ice skate at and sort them alphabetically:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <parks>
        <park>
            <park_name>MCGUANE (JOHN)</park_name>
            <acres>10.3</acres>
            <iceskating>0</iceskating>
        </park>
        <park>
            <park_name>ARMOUR (PHILIP) SQUARE</park_name>
            <acres>9.05</acres>
            <iceskating>0</iceskating>
        </park>
        <park>
            <park_name>FULLER (MELVILLE)</park_name>
            <acres>11.31</acres>
            <iceskating>1</iceskating>
        </park>
        <park>
            <park_name>CORNELL (PAUL) SQUARE</park_name>
            <acres>8.8</acres>
            <iceskating>1</iceskating>
        </park>
        <park>
            <park_name>RUSSELL (MARTIN) SQUARE</park_name>
            <acres>10.05</acres>
            <iceskating>2</iceskating>
        </park>
</parks>
```

Here is my XSL file. If the child element "iceskating" contains a value greater than 0, I want it to apply a template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="results">
            <xsl:element name="iceskating_parks">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="parks/park">
                    <xsl:sort select="park_name" order="ascending" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="iceskating" >
        <xsl:if test="iceskating &gt; 0">
            <park name="{park_name}" acres="{acres}" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

I want the transformed XML file to be formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <iceskating_parks>
        <park name="PARK NAME" acres="99.99"/>
        <park name="PARK NAME" acres="99.99"/>
        <park name="PARK NAME" acres="99.99"/>
    </iceskating_parks>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the condition into the apply-templates e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="parks/park[iceskating &gt; 0]">
```

and keep the `match="park"` from previous suggestions, instead of switching to `match="iceskating"`.